# I am looking for i-Lids dataset for AVSS 2007

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, database, video

I am looking for the i-Lids dataset for AVSS 2007 but I am unable to find it online. The link for the data on the [official website](http://www.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/~andrea/avss2007_d.html) is broken. More specifically, I am interested in the abandoned baggage (AB) data, which have been used extensively in the literature.

I have only found a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fpTG4ELZ3bE) for the "easy" scenario (AVSS AB Easy).

Does anybody know where I can find the i-Lids AVSS AB data or have a copy that they could share?

Comment: didn't find it quick at on the wayback machine: archive.org

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing I'm able to download it via anonymous ftp at ftp://motinas.elec.qmul.ac.uk/pub/iLids/

[image: i-Lids bag detection challenge]

Comment: it seems that the link is no more reachable. Do you have a new one? Thanks for sharing.

Comment: I get `Could not connect to server` when trying to connect to that FTP server using FileZilla.